# Mirror Shape Key Drivers

Tags: rigging, drivers

I have a symmetrical model, with pairs of symmetrical (along the X-axis) shape keys (ending with "L" and "R"), driven by a symmetrical armature (bone names ending with "L" and "R").

Is there a way to "mirror" all of the drivers which have been applied to the "L" shapekeys to the "R" shapekeys (swapping all of the "L" bones for "R" bones in the driver targets) in one go?

Perhaps even mirror the shapekeys, bones and drivers all at once?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I would really like to know this also - maybe some add-on somewhere, hmm